# Dropdownlist in yii

Tags: php, select, yii

I have a problem with a dropdownlist created in Yii. I wanted to create a dropdown list with sample below:

```
<select id="con_id">    
<option value="1">Con 1</option>
<option value="2">Con 2</option>
<option value="3">Con 3</option>
<option value="4">Con 4</option>
<option value="5">Con 5</option>
<option value="6">Con 6</option>
<option value="all">--All--</option>
</select>
```

Dropdown menu list are obtained from the database. Below is the sample code that I created in Yii format:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, '_conId', array_merge(CHtml::listData(Consultant::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('client_id' => '--All--')));
```

However, the result of the dropdown list created in Yii become like this:

```
<select id="con_id">    
<option value="">Con 1</option>
<option value="1">Con 2</option>
<option value="2">Con 3</option>
<option value="3">Con 4</option>
<option value="4">Con 5</option>
<option value="5">Con 6</option>
<option value="all">--All--</option>
</select>
```

The value on the option is not correctly assigned. Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**
Somehow I have found the solution:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, '_conId', array('all' => '--All--') + CHtml::listData(Consultant::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an 'empty' option for CHtml::listData, where you can set the text for the 'empty' option.

Here's an example using your code:

```php
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    '_conId',
    CHtml::listData(
        Consultant::model()->findAll(),'id','name'), // list all data from model
        array('empty'=>'--All--') // set empty data label
); ?>
```